# next() not working in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

this is **my app.js**

```
 function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
}

/**
 * Routes
 */
var index = require('./routes/index');
var dashboard = require('./routes/dashboard');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/dashboard', requireLogin, dashboard);
```

**routes/dashboard.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('dashboard/index', {}); 
    });

module.exports = router;
```

After doing the login I am directed to the route `/dashboard`, but I get a status 404.
If I try to remove the function `requireLogin`, the route `/dashboard` is visible and working.

Why? 
I did some tests, and I saw that the problem is next().
For the login I used [passport](http://passportjs.org/) is working well.

Comment: Can you show dashboard route file

Comment: ok done, I have added the file.

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure you template file is where you expect it?

Comment: Yes, because if I try delete the function "requireLogin" from my route in app.js, the `/dashboard` route works. :(

Comment: nobody can help me? :(

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven't figured out you can put `return next()` instead of `next()`.
So this:

```
 function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
}
```

Should become this:

```
 function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
}
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

Actually I had a very similar issue, for me it wasn't anything to do with the middleware that was handling authentication, it was the way my routes were set up.
I think you are trying to receive GET requests on a route you want to POST credentials to in `dashboard.js`:

```
router.route('/')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard/index', {}); 
});
```

should be:

```
router.route('/')
.post(function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('dashboard/index', {}); 
});
```

since you are posting credentials to that route.